# How to setup two jquery cookies?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm developing java ee application, and I have one page that uses the same cookie for different users, which is not right. So I copied jquery.cookie.js file and created a new one with the name jquery.cookie2.js, and I changed the call script as well, it worked but it has the same action. Whatever I do in the old user happens in the new. I thought it might be the cookie name so I changed it from

```
jQuery.cookie
```

to

```
jQuery.cookie2
```

after that it didn't work.
here is the code for the cookie

```
jQuery.cookie = function(name, value, options) {
if (typeof value != 'undefined') { // name and value given, set cookie
    options = options || {};
    if (value === null) {
        value = '';
        options.expires = -1;
    }
    var expires = '';
    if (options.expires && (typeof options.expires == 'number' || options.expires.toUTCString)) {
        var date;
        if (typeof options.expires == 'number') {
            date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (options.expires * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        } else {
            date = options.expires;
        }
        expires = '; expires=' + date.toUTCString(); // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
    }
    // CAUTION: Needed to parenthesize options.path and options.domain
    // in the following expressions, otherwise they evaluate to undefined
    // in the packed version for some reason...
    var path = options.path ? '; path=' + (options.path) : '';
    var domain = options.domain ? '; domain=' + (options.domain) : '';
    var secure = options.secure ? '; secure' : '';
    document.cookie = [name, '=', encodeURIComponent(value), expires, path, domain, secure].join('');
} else { // only name given, get cookie
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
};
```

My question is how to use different cookies for one application?

Answer (score 0):

You have just copied and pasted the source code for the cookie module, which will not help you. Remove jquery.cookie2.js. If you want to use two different cookies, then set the values of two different cookies:

```
//Set values
$.cookie('user1', 'firstValue');
$.cookie('user2', 'differentValue');

//Retrieve values
$.cookie('user1'); //Returns 'firstValue'
$.cookie('user2'); //Returns 'differentValue'
```

I'm not sure that you need to use cookies though, especially if your goal is to load some information client-side for different users on the same machine/browser. Please see this answer for details on an alternative using `localStorage`, especially if you don't need the information to be sent to the server on every page load: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28253089/830125.